# Get date from timestamp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get date from "2015-07-31 06:03:21" using Laravel query builder?
In normal query using DATE() we can get date easily, but I don't know how to use DATE() in Laravel query builder. Please check my code sample given below and correct me?

Normal Query

```
SELECT DATE('2015-07-31 06:03:21'), customer_id FROM customer_histories
```

Laravel Query Builder

```
$customerhistory = Customerhistory::where('customer_id', 1)
            ->select('freetext', 'DATE(created_at)')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `DB::raw()`, though if you are only selecting it, why not just take created_at complete? By default, [Eloquent will convert](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to instances of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) so you can handle it like this in your code:

```
$customerhistory = Customerhistory::where('customer_id', 1)
            ->select('freetext', 'created_at')
            ->get();

dd($customerhistory[0]->created_at->toDateString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DB::raw('something')` for that. In this case your raw input will be treated as part of actual SQL.

This is something you might wanna give a try:

```
$customerhistory = Customerhistory::where('customer_id', 1)
    ->select('freetext', DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`)'))
    ->get();
```

More details and yet another example cal be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects).

Also it looks like you're using eloquent. You might wanna check the [mutators section](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators).

Answer (score 0):

```
$customerhistory = Customerhistory::where('customer_id', '=', '1')
            ->select('freetext', DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`)'))
            ->get();
```

Thanks.